# Get Facebook Page Likes in PHP (after FQL depreciation)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I used to be able to get the page likes with a single FQL query URL on Facebook. But as of last week, they shut it down. Demanding to use their SDK or API, however my system scans facebook pages from my users and displays their page likes.

Is there any way I can get around this, as if I use the SDK or API. I need an app for each request for each page.

Thanks.

Note: 
I tried using headers & user agents to no joy with `file_get_contents()` & tried on a mobile phone request to no avail.

Code:

```
$url = "http://m.facebook.com/pagename/";

$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7\r\n" 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print_r($file);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wiht each user you will have to get the access_token to get the user infor by the facebook api. form the api response, you can get what you want now.

Comment: _“however my system scans facebook pages from my users”_ – scraping their pages without prior written consent by Facebook is against their ToS, so what you have been doing wasn’t allowed already. Using their API is the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this question is downvoted. Previously we used to get like / share count using fql which is depreciated after august 7,2016. We can use this trick to get the like count.

Just make a curl request to facebook & parse the result.

```
   $domain='stackoverflow.com';  
   $protocol='http://';  
   $orgin=$protocol.$domain.'/';
   $url='http://stackoverflow.com';

   $param=array('action'=>'like','app_id'=>'','channel'=>'http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/lUqP5iIjiw6.js?version=42#cb=f178d9075b06a6a',
   'domain'=>$domain,'orgin'=>$orgin,'relation'=>'parent.parent','container_width'=>0,'href'=>$url,'layout'=>'button_count','locale'=>'en_GB','sdk'=>'joey',
   'share'=>false,'show_faces'=>true,'size'=>'large');

   $fb_url='https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/plugins/like.php?';

   $ch= curl_init();
   $options=array( 
   CURLOPT_URL => $fb_url.http_build_query($param),
   CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
   CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE =>1,
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01;Windows NT 5.0)",
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0, 
   CURLOPT_REFERER=>$orgin,
   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=> 10,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>40
  );

  curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
  $fb_html=curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch)>0){ #checks any curl error
   $fbc='';
  }else{ 
   $fb_html=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$fb_html);
   preg_match('/<span[^>]*id="u_0_3">(.*?)<\/span>/sm',$fb_html,$count);
   $fbc=$count[1];  
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  echo "Like count:$fbc";
```

Check this post for detailed explanation:[get facebook like/share count after fql depreciation](http://webdevelopmentscripts.com/79-best-way-to-get-facebook-like-share-count-after-fql-depreciation-php)